# Bash command "read" behaviour using redirection operator

Tags: linux, bash, process-substitution

If I execute the following command:

```
> read someVariable _ < <(echo "54 41")
```

and:

```
> echo $someVariable
```

The result is: `54`.

What does `< <` (with spaces) do?

Why is `_` giving the first word from the result in the "echo" command?

The commands above are just example.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please show the output of `read someVariable _ < <(echo "54 41") ; echo "$_"`

Comment: `read var1 var2` sets `var1` to the first "word" of input, and `var2` to the second "word". So `read someVariable _` sets `someVariable` to the first "word" (in this case "54"), and a variable named underscore to the second "word" ("41").

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson. greetings.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process Substitution

As [tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) explains,

> Process substitution feeds the output of a process (or processes) into
>   the stdin of another process.

So in effect this is similar to piping [stdout](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/ksh-1.html) of one command to the other , e.g. `echo foobar barfoo | wc` . But notice: in the [bash manpage][3] you will see that it is denoted as `<(list)`. So basically you can redirect output of multiple (!) commands.

Note: technically when you say < < you aren't referring to one thing, but two redirection with single < and process redirection of output from <( . . .).

Now what happens if we do just process substitution?

```
$ echo <(echo bar)
/dev/fd/63
```

As you can see, the shell creates temporary file descriptor `/dev/fd/63` where the output goes. That means  `<` redirects that file descriptor as input into a command.

So very simple example would be to make process substitution of output from two echo commands into wc:

```
$ wc < <(echo bar;echo foo)
      2       2       8
```

So here we make shell create a file descriptor for all the output that happens in the parenthesis and redirect that as input to wc .As expected, wc receives that stream from two echo commands, which by itself would output two lines, each having a word, and appropriately we have 2 words, 2 lines, and 6 characters plus two newlines counted.

**Side Note**: Process substitution may be referred to as a bashism (a command or structure usable in advanced shells like bash, but not specified by POSIX), but it was implemented in ksh before bash's existence as [ksh man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/ksh-1.html). Shells like `tcsh` and `mksh` however do not have process substitution. So how could we go around redirecting output of multiple commands into another command without process substitution? Grouping plus piping!

```
$ (echo foo;echo bar) | wc
      2       2       8
```

Effectively this is the same as above example, However, this is different under the hood from process substitution, since we make stdout of the whole subshell and stdin of `wc` [linked with the pipe][5]. On the other hand, process substitution makes a command read a temporary file descriptor.

So if we can do grouping with piping, why do we need process substitution? Because sometimes we cannot use piping. Consider the example below - comparing outputs of two commands with `diff` (which needs two files, and in this case we are giving it two file descriptors)

```
diff <(ls /bin) <(ls /usr/bin)
```

Comment: For completeness, note that the creation of `/dev/fd/63` is an implementation detail of process substitution. A different implementation of `bash` (for a platform without `/dev/fd`, for example) might used named pipes instead. `echo <(echo bar)` in that case might output something like `/tmp/fifo1`, if `bash` created a named pipe called `fifo1` in the `/tmp` directory.

Comment: thanks a lot Aman Gupta; now is more clear the concept. also Thank you for your contribution @chepner.